# Why can't I add or remove a QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I have two `ListWidget` at my `ui` and I want to move one `QListWidgetItem` from `availableMeasurementsListWidget` to `selectedMeasurementListWidget`

But this won't work for me. Nothing adds into `selectedMeasurementListWidget` and the item does not removes from `availableMeasurementsListWidget`. Why?

That only who works is displaying the text of the `qDebug() << item->text();`

```
void ChartSettingsWindow::on_availableMeasurementsListWidget_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    QListWidgetItem *item = ui->availableMeasurementsListWidget->currentItem();
    qDebug() << item->text();
   ui->selectedMeasurementListWidget->addItem(item);
    ui->availableMeasurementsListWidget->removeItemWidget(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`QListWidget:: removeItemWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget) doesn't remove the `QListWidgetItem` from the `QListWidget`: it only...

> Removes the widget set on the given item.
>
> To remove an item (row) from the list entirely, either delete the item
> or use takeItem().

So you probably want something like...

```
auto *available = ui->availableMeasurementsListWidget;
auto *selected  = ui->selectedMeasurementListWidget;
auto *item      = available->currentItem();
selected->addItem(available->takeItem(available->indexFromItem(item).row()));
```